# Structure with List of Nested Structure

Tags: c, struct, structure

I have this challenge that I'm not achieving how to solve, any help would be appreciated.

So I need a structure that has a list of nested structures, is this possible to do in C?

The user will input an animal and it's value per line, this is supposed to be saved and then to be printed orderer by value. These animal can have some subitens and the subitens have it's own value too...

Something like this:

```
struct item
{
 char *name;
 float value;
}

struct animal
{
 char *name;
 float value;
 struct item;
}
```

Or is it the struct approach a wrong approach?

Anyway can we initialize as many structure as inputs given?
Thanks

I have tried arrays, but I doesn't seem the best path to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, you can have a structure inside another structure.

Comment: You can also have an array inside a struct.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm going to explore further

Answer (score -1):

you could try this sample that I have, tell me if it works.

```
import requests
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional, List

class Item:
    def __init__(self, name: str, value: float):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name: str, value: float, items: Optional[List[Item]] = None):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.items = items or []

@dataclass
class ani_search:
    user: Optional[User] = None
    name_media: Optional[str] = None
    name_char: Optional[str] = None
    rank: Optional[int] = None
    type: Optional[str] = None
    genre: Optional[list] = None
    id_char: Optional[int] = None
    id_media: Optional[int] = None
    page: Optional[int]= 1
    page_char: Optional[int]= 1
    search_type: Optional[str]= None
    iter = 0

animals = []

while True:
    name = input('Enter the animal name: ')
    if name == 'done':
        break
    value = float(input('Enter the animal value: '))

    animal = Animal(name, value)

    while True:
        item_name = input('Enter the item name (or "done" to finish): ')
        if item_name == 'done':
            break
        item_value = float(input('Enter the item value: '))

        item = Item(item_name, item_value)
        animal.items.append(item)

    animals.append(animal)

for animal in sorted(animals, key=lambda a: a.
```

Comment: Your help is much appreciated, but that is neither ```C``` code, nor relevant to the question. There is no concept of classes in ```C```.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your wish to help is appreciated. Nevertheless your answer is off topic here as it does not take into account what language tags were added to the question. Any answer should be valid in the tagged language, i.e. C in this case.